# How to search for a string in a file and compare?

Tags: c, linux, string, file

That is my first post on stackoverflow.
Btw I am really noob.

I would like to search a string with a comand like that: `./a.out foobar`.

I have a file, called `list.txt`, in which I have a list of names, I want to search in that file to find `foobar`. When I will find it I would like to add a grade next to the string.

My function:

```
void rate(char *name, int grade)
{
 FILE *fprt;

 fprt = fopen("list.txt", "r+");

 if(fprt != NULL)
 {
    fclose(fprt);
 }
 else
   printf("[!]The file wasn't opened correctly.");
}
```

How can I compare the `argv[1]` with all strings in the file? And How I can add a number next to the string?

I really do not know how to do it. Maybe someone can do the function and explain it to me?

Thanks to everyone in advance. Sorry if the post is stupid.

P.S.:
My attempt, still missing.

```
void rate(char *name)                                                         
{                                                                             
  FILE *fprt;                                                                 
  fprt = fopen("list.txt", "r+");                                             

  if(fprt == NULL)                                                            
    return -1;                                                                

  while(fgets(name, sizeof(name), fprt) != NULL)                              
    {                                                                         
      if(strcmp(argv[1], name) != NULL)                                       
        puts("Found a match.\n");                                             
    }                                                                         
}
```

Comment: This can help you: https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-searching-for-strings-in-a-text-file

Comment: I still do not understand. Once discovered that the string exists, and matches the string entered by the user how do I to:
verify that the string is there without printing anything?
And how do I add the vote?

Comment: "How can I compare the argv[1] with all strings in the file?" --> Nothing in the code does any comparing.  Post what you have attempted.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.
I added my last attempt. It sucks, I know...

Comment: if you want to get better at this, you'll have to spend the time to learn how to use the debugger, usually `gdb`. Look for a tutorial on simple code and see what you can find about what values are being assigned to your variables (and when) particularly `name`. As is your code needs a `main()` so people can copy/paste it into a `c` environment and run it, so you might want to add that as well to your Q. Good luck.

Comment: `name` is a pointer, so `sizeof(name)` will be the sizeof a pointer. (usually 32 or 64 bits, depending on compile options and the underlying hardware architecture.  and `sizeof` is a compile time operator, not a run time operator (note the latest version of C has it both ways)  suggest using the function: `strlen()` rather than `sizeof`  and remember to add 1 to allow for the trailing NUL byte

Comment: since the current posted code is reading in the whole line, then plan on each line in the file to be the same length, say 50 bytes..  Then can update the line in memory with the value of 'vote', then call `fseek( fptr, -50, SEEK_CURRENT);` then call `fprintf( fptr, "%50.50s", name );`

Comment: to make the comparison between the file contents and the argv[1] string, you could use `sscanf()` to extract the file contents string, then use `strcmp()` to make the actual comparison

Comment: Note: if the lines in the file are not long enough, then will have to open a NEW file and code such that each line in the new file is long enough to contain both the name and the vote